# 404 fail while trying to run spring boot app from start.spring.io

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

When I'm starting my mini project in spring boot (which mostly I generated from start.spring.io) from command line by command mvn spring-boot:run and walk to the **http://localhost:8080/test/{michal}** I see the 404 fail.

Beside that I can't create return statement in controller class using Response.create -> it shows:

> The method create(String) is undefined for the type Response

I think this is the main problem why my app doesn't want to run properly.

**This is my controller class**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response<String> /*@ResponseBody String*/ getWelcomeText(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        return Response.create(testService.loadWelcomeText(name));
    }

}
```

**This is my service class**

```
@Service
public class TestService {
   public String loadWelcomeText(String name) {
       return "Hello " + name;
   }
}
```

I have @ComponentScan annotation

[image: How it looks in my project]

Comment: It's better to modify you original post instead of adding answers with details. Could you delete your "answers" and update the post? Also you're using a bit strange URL `http://localhost:8080/test/{michal}`. Why it has curly braces? Do you really need them?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Looking at package layout you need to add `@ComponentScan("com.bielawski.michal")` annotation on your main class to tell spring-boot where to locate controller and service (or move main class to `com.bielawski.michal` package).

Comment: I answerd you above with screen how It looks in my project

Comment: I've changed what you said and still have the same problem with Response.create

Answer (score 0):

It's like this: I have @ComponentScan annotation

[How it looks in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgWbG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your use of `Response` instead of `ResponseEntity`. Not sure where you got documentation that said to use `Response` but the official documentation describes it here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-httpentity

Constructors for using `ReponseEntity` are: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html